# Is it possible to implement a "Vim" toggle in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Ie, specify  [ctrl][alt]+v or something...and that would instance vim inside that text editor window...  because that would be really cool.

And/Or: is there a way to do it yourself, if you wanted to? Ie, can you attach custom functions to the keyboard keys and whatnot?  I noticed that a lot of the Add-Ins seem to be able to kindof accomplish that level of customizability...

Comment: Again, please do not edit your questions in this manner. You completely change its meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few projects that incorporate vim keybindings directly into the Visual Studio editor.

Here's one: [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329)

Comment: And you can toggle VsVim on/off using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329)
You download the plugin from the link above, double click on it and it will be installed in all VisualStudios you have installed in your computer.

About toggling VIM in VisualStudio:
I don't think you can enable/disable it per tab or file openned: either is enabled or disabled in all files.
What you could do is this: add a new shortcut to enable or disable it when you need it.

**Tools -> Options... -> Environment -> Keyboard**
On the "Show commands containing" input type "**VsVim.ToggleEnabled**". For me this command wasn't bind it with anything. I added the shortcut
Ctrl Q, Ctrl V